# Two dimensional Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Can someone please explain me why:

$T_4((x,y);f,(0,0)) = xy - 0.5x^2y^2$

with: $f(x,y) = \log{(1+xy)} \cdot \cos{(2x^2)}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables

Answer (score 1):

Using Rudin W. - Principles of mathematical analysis-(1976) pages 243-244, Murray H. Protter, Charles B. Jr. Morrey - Intermediate Calculus (2012) page 252 we know, that Taylor formula in case of 2 variables is
$$f(x,y)=f(a,b) + \sum\limits_{1 \leqslant s+r \leqslant p}\frac{\partial^{r+s}f(a,b)}{\partial x^r \partial y^s}\frac{(x-a)^r}{r!}\frac{(y-b)^s}{s!}+R_p=\\=f(a,b) + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{p}\frac{1}{k!}\left((x-a)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ (y-b)\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)^{\{k\}}f(a,b)+R_p$$
where $R_p$ is remainder.

In your case, assuming $\log = \log_{c}$, you need to calculate
$$\begin{array}{}f(0,0)=0, \\ \frac{\partial f(0,0)}{\partial x}=\frac{y\cos 2x^2-4x\ln (1+xy) \sin 2x^2(1+xy)}{\ln c (1+xy)} \big|_{(x,y)=(0,0)} =0, \\ \frac{\partial f(0,0)}{\partial y}=\frac{x \cos 2x^2}{\ln c (1+xy)} \big|_{(x,y)=(0,0)}=0 \\
\frac{\partial^2 f(0,0)}{\partial y^2} = -\frac{x^2 \cos 2x^2}{\ln c (1+xy)^2} \big|_{(x,y)=(0,0)}=0\\
\frac{\partial^2 f(0,0)}{\partial x \partial y} =\frac{-4yx^3\sin(2x^2)-4x^2\sin(2x^2) + \cos(2x^2)}{\ln c (1+xy)^2} \big|_{(x,y)=(0,0)}=\frac{1}{\ln c}\\
\cdots
\end{array}$$
up to member you wish.